# Strptime behaves differently in console and in script

Tags: datetime, python-3.8, miniconda

Python v3.8.5
conda v4.9.2

Here is the code I run:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
date_str = '1957 Oct 4 1928:34'
date_object = dt.strptime(date_str, "%Y %b %d %H%M:%S")
```

This will work perfectly from command line:

```
~/code/ » python                                             
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 07:30:14) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> str = '1957 Oct 4 1928:34'
>>> date_object = dt.strptime(str, "%Y %b %d %H%M:%S")
>>> date_object
datetime.datetime(1957, 10, 4, 19, 28, 34)
>>>
```

But will fail when I run it from a script:

```
(calmenv) -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
~/code/ » which python                                       
/home/bipbip/anaconda3/envs/calmenv/bin/python
(calmenv) -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
~/code » python --version                                   
Python 3.8.5
(calmenv) -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
~/code » python bin/datamanager.py --launch_tb              
date_str in try: '1957 Oct 4 1928:34'
time data '1957 Oct 4 1928:34' does not match format '%Y %b %d %H%M:%S'
```

The script is launched in a conda environment. The version of python is the same in both cases. The conda environment is always active.

Digging around in the datetime.py file, I found out that the regex used by strptime to convert the string is not the same in both cases.
From case 1 (command line, success case):

```
data_string in strptime fn: 1957 Oct 4 1928:34
format_regex in strptime: re.compile('(?P<Y>\\d\\d\\d\\d)\\s+(?P<b>jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)\\s+(?P<d>3[0-1]|[1-2]\\d|0[1-9]|[1-9]| [1-9])\\s+(?P<H>2[0-3]|[0-1]\\d|\\d)(?P<M>[0-5]\\d|\\d):(?P<S>6[0-1]|[0-5]\\d|\\d), re.IGNORECASE)
```

From case 2 (script, fail case):

```
data_string in strptime fn: 1957 Oct 4 1928:34
format_regex in strptime: re.compile('(?P<Y>\\d\\d\\d\\d)\\s+(?P<b>janv\\.|févr\\.|avril|juil\\.|sept\\.|mars|juin|août|oct\\.|nov\\.|déc\\.|mai)\\s+(?P<d>3[0-1]|[1-2]\\d|0[1-9]|[1-9]| [1-9])\\s+(?P<H>2[0-3]|[0-1]\\d|\\d)(?P<M>[0-5]\\d|\, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Why is strptime taking 2 different regexes to validate the string format, depending on where it is called from ?

Comment: Clearly the first case is using English but the second case is using a locale (French?). It's also possible that the Python versions used are not the same and you are trying to use a wrong directive for said Python version. We can't really tell because the images (which you shouldn't use in a question BTW) are cropped

Comment: The version of python is the same in both cases. The _strptime.py file used by both processes is the same.  I did not get a wrong directive error, but format match error. Why is strptime using locale values in one scenario and not in the other ? 
I have replaced images with code, did not know this was bad practice. Thank you for your answer

Comment: You can confirm the locale. Add `import locale ; print(locale.getlocale())` to the script. If it is set to anything then search for `setlocale` calls in the script

Comment: I have found a workaround. Before call to problematic strptime, I set locale manually, then reset afterwards. The problem came from strptime's _getlang function (that wraps locale.getlocale(locale.LC_TIME)) returns different results depending on if launched from console or script. Thank you for your time @DeepSpace